# do i have to be connected to the internet when running the emulator i created in the AVD manager?

Tags: android, android-emulator

do i have to be connected to the internet when running the emulator i created in the AVD manager? i'm totally new to android programming, hope that someone can help me. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. Not at all. Unless you are running an app that needs internet.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to be connected to the internet for the emulator to run.  However, if your application requires internet access (ex. WebView, URLConnection, etc), then yes, you will need to be connected to the internet for those features to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
An Android Virtual Device (AVD) is an emulator configuration that lets you 
model an actual device by defining hardware and software options to be emulated 
by the Android Emulator.
```

**do i have to be connected to the internet when running the emulator i created in the AVD manager?**

No, you don't have to be connected to internet connection when running emulator until unless you are running some internet connection required application.

You can go through [developer link](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html) to now more.

If you are confused about managing AVD then [go through this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)